# Difference betwen Amount of records and alive counter

Tags: arangodb

after copying a whole collection (A) into another (B),  statistics differ:
- collection statistics A say: 1.7 Mio records
- collection statistics B say: 1.6 Mio records
- direct scan (via RETURN LENGTH(FOR i in A/B RETURN a._key)) count 1.7 Mio records (for both collections).

There are no dead records.

What are those statistics telling me, though?

Comment: Which version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statistics returned by `collection.figures()` contain some values that exclude documents that are only stored in the write-ahead logs.

When documents are stored in a collection, they will be written in the write-ahead log first. They will eventually be copied into datafiles of the collection. Only at this point the collection figures will be updated. 
So it is definitely possible that the counters differ even if the collections contain the same number of documents and even the same data. It is also possible to have the collection figures report alive sizes and counts of 0 even if the collection contains documents.

That figures do not contain information about documents contained in the write-ahead logs is stated in the docs for figures ([Collection Methods](https://docs.arangodb.com/Collections/CollectionMethods.html) and [Getting Information](https://docs.arangodb.com/HttpCollection/Getting.html)):

> Documents that are contained in the write-ahead log only are not
>   reported in this figure.

Regardless of the above, the `count()` method will always return the exact number of (alive) documents in the collection.

Comment: THANKS ... that also explains why after the next start the figures became consistent.